# What are the effective strategies to increase GPA?

Tags: undergraduate, gpa

I am doing Undergraduate in Software Engineering and am going to finish my third semester (total of 8 semesters) now and as with my calculation, I am going to end it with a GPA of mere 1.89. I know this is a very low GPA, and this is because I failed my calculus II and Data Structure class. It might be very difficult to raise this GPA but I believe I still have time to make up and reach at least 2.5. Now since I don't want to set my goals too high or I might end up miserably disappointed, I want to know if this is even possible? Will a GPA of 2.5 be too bad for life career? And what are the strategies I can take to get my goals or even higher if possible anyhow?

### Reasons of previous failures

To point out causes of failing previous semesters, I am studying in a foreign land and hence the language difference is the biggest problem in communication and even understanding lectures. Recently, I have also been suffering from a lot of anxiety and have been having symptoms of depression (as I have read on Internet, I don't know till what extent they are true). I have been losing my social life and feeling just nothing at all. I have a part time job as well to support my personal finance.

So what can I do to tackle with my personal anxiety and make up for the bad scores I had earlier? Do I still have enough time for that? And how high can I reach?

Comment: Study hard. *Really* understand the material, working through it. Check sources other than the textbook, the lecturer and the teaching assistants. There is no royal road, sorry. Yes, your "social" life will suffer. Even so, when you later get a job, you'll fondly remember your "wild years" at college ;-)

Comment: _Will a GPA of 2.5 be too bad for life career?_ — Ahem.  **NO.**  (My undergraduate GPA was below 2.5.)

Comment: I strongly disagree with the close votes.  Graduate students also have GPAs, also have part-time jobs, also have to deal with language/culture issues in foreign countries, and also have to deal with depression.

Comment: @JeffE So you mean with a GPA of 2.5, i can still be accepted in a comparatively nice, or lets say reputed companies? And if I would like to apply for masters, is it going to be tough because of that GPA. Well first, I need to get that at least.

Comment: In my personal experience with companies, especially in computer science, some will ask about your GPA, and if it's under 3 they will decline. But some will not ask at all, because they don't really care, and some will be fine with a low GPA especially if you have other positive factors going for you (like work experience especially, or if you just interview well). With about 1 year of experience I don't know that you'll ever be asked about your GPA again in your life, and within a few years you'll need to mention you have a degree but almost no one will ask you details about it.

Comment: And for graduate schools, low GPA isn't great, but as JeffE points out it isn't an automatic disqualification for that either. And with less than half of your degree completed, 0.6 measly GPA points is certainly not an impossible aspiration by any stretch of the imagination. Institutions vary, but many allow retakes to replace a failing grade, and even if not then becoming a B+ student would get above your target GPA. Having problems in the first half of your degree program after moving to a new country does not, in and of itself, disqualify you from hardly anything at all in life.